# ASP.NET MVC - Hidden Field binded doesn't contain value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm having a trouble with my project (ASP.NET MVC 5/AJAX/BOOTSTRAP).

When click on Save button on Page, .Net calls in POST the proper action, but the Hidden Fields for PSATOKEN does not contain value (see @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PSAToken) in the View), despite PSAToken contains a GUID value (saw in Debug Mode) in the Controller method.

Let's see some code below.

Many thanks to answerers!

**Model**

```
public interface IPSAPageViewModel
{
    String PSAToken { get; set; }
    int IdPSAAzienda { get; set; }
}
public abstract class BasePSAPageViewModel : IPSAPageViewModel
{
    public String PSAToken { get; set; }
    public int IdPSAAzienda { get; set; }
}
public class DatiGeneraliViewModel : BasePSAPageViewModel 
{
    public DatiGeneraliViewModel()
    {
        this.Item = new InformazioniGenerali();
    }
    public Crea.PSA.ServiceLayer.BO.InformazioniGenerali Item { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> FormeGiuridicheList { set; get; }
    public List<SelectListItem> FormeConduzioneList { set; get; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
   private ViewResult ViewPSAPage(IPSAPageViewModel vm)
    {
        base.createViewBagPaginePrecSucc();
        return View(vm);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpParamAction]
    public ActionResult SalvaDatiGeneraliProsegui(DatiGeneraliViewModel vm)
    {
        return salvataggioDatiGenerali(vm, true);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpParamAction]
    public ActionResult SalvaDatiGenerali(DatiGeneraliViewModel vm)
    {
        //Here vm.PSAToken doesn't contain the value setted 
        return salvataggioDatiGenerali(vm);
    }

    private ActionResult salvataggioDatiGenerali(DatiGeneraliViewModel vm, bool proseguiCompilazione = false)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var resp = aziendeManager.Save(vm.PSAToken, vm.Item, SessionManager.UserIdConnected, CONTROLLERNAME);
            if (resp.Success)
            {
                var psaAzienda = resp.DataObject;
                setVarsInSession(psaAzienda.idToken.ToString(), psaAzienda.idPsaAzienda.ToString(), psaAzienda.Aziende.ragioneSociale);

                //Here there is some Value (POST)
                vm.PSAToken = psaAzienda.idToken.ToString();
                //vm.IdPSAAzienda = psaAzienda.idPsaAzienda.ToString();

                if (proseguiCompilazione)
                    return RedirectToAction("DatiAziendaliRiepilogativi", new { id = psaAzienda.idToken });
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", resp.Message);
        }
        setSuccessMessage();
        vm.FormeGiuridicheList = aziendeManager.GetAllFormeGiuridiche().ToSelectItems();
        vm.FormeConduzioneList = aziendeManager.GetAllFormeConduzione().ToSelectItems();
        return ViewPSAPage(vm);
    }
```

**View**

to see the view click [here](https://gist.github.com/karletto/40e1111bb4d4dc79a592edbed1aa113a)

[Here](https://ibb.co/muf5E6) you can see the value at debug in VS

But in the generated HTML the Hidden Field of PSATOKEN is empty

Comment: what is `this.Item` ? I don't see any Item member there

Comment: Is this the actual code for DatiGeneraliViewModel though? It doesn't seem that it would compile. The error might be in the real code.

Comment: @derloopkat & Adam Brown - I truncated it to make it more readable...now I add it

Comment: Can you include your entire view markup please?

Comment: Why vm.PSAToken in post method is null in your opinion? What do I check for fix?

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML - does the hidden form element get created correctly? You could also put a breakpoint in the View.

Comment: @JohnM - in the generated HTML the value is null (<input id="PSAToken" name="PSAToken" type="hidden" value="" />)  but in Debug before the rendering the page vm.PSAToken is properly setted!

Comment: @timothyclifford I tried to paste whole code of the view but stackoverflow give me troubles for the formatting ...

Comment: @Charles, I have tested your code and it works for me. The Html generated was `<input id="PSAToken" name="PSAToken" type="hidden" value="0000022121445">`, when I submit the form my Network tab shows https://ibb.co/c4s6mm and controller gets the value https://ibb.co/dhgcsR. We need to be able to reproduce the problem with the code you posted here.

Comment: @Charles, let's check something more trivial. Since you return View without specifying the name, I understand the view name is "DatiGenerali". Is that correct? Is that the view you posted here? Is it possible that you have more than one form tag in resulting Html page? (check the source code in your browser)

Comment: I shared my files here: https://gist.github.com/karletto/40e1111bb4d4dc79a592edbed1aa113a
 thx a lots

Comment: in that code you `return ViewPSAPage(vm);` from `public ActionResult DatiGenerali(string id)`. What is ViewPSAPage?

Comment: @derloopkat - I commented that call to solve the trouble, but the result is the same...anyway the code is this:       private ViewResult ViewPSAPage(IPSAPageViewModel vm)
        {
            base.createViewBagPaginePrecSucc();
            return View(vm);
        }

Comment: @Charles, my question is because `View(vm)` returns different views depending on where you call it. Anyway the code you posted does not reproduce the problem so it is waste of time and violates Stackoverflow rules.

Comment: @timothyclifford you're right..sorry! 
I had a trouble to paste code in stackoverflow...I tried to simplify to save the question. 
I will try to edit the Question to repair. Thanks to everyone for your attention

Comment: @timothyclifford I hope now It's be good

Comment: I found the solution here: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object .
Thank you anyway and I'm so sorry to have wasted your time (I understood the lesson)... :) Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: 
[patrickdesjardins.com/blog/…](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object) .